# How to create subdomain automatically when customer is registering in Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, subdomain

suppose when a customer is registering in our sample rails application we have a text field for subdomain.how to create that subdomain automatically and permit users of our customer to login just from that subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a simple text field for the `subdomain`, you only need to change [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope constraints: SubDomain do
   devise_for :users
end

#lib/sub_domain.rb
module SubDomain

    def initializer(router)
        @router = router
    end

    def self.matches?(request)
        User.exists? subdomain: request.subdomain
    end

end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, request_keys: [:subdomain]

   def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
      where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :subdomain => warden_conditions[:subdomain]).first
   end
end
```

Because the `session_store` will be scoped to a single tld (top level domain), you'll only have to change the above.

---

**Bonus**

A better way to do it would be to automatically set the subdomain, from their `username` or something.

You'll be best using [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to create a "slug" (which you can [alias](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) as  `subdomain`):

```
#Gemfile
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'

# You'll have to follow friendly_id's install instructions

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]
   alias_attribute :subdomain, :slug
end
```

This will automatically set the user's subdomain, which you'll be able to use with the code in the top part of the answer to direct them to the appropriate actions etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it